# django (memcached) not caching objects

Tags: python, django, memcached

Can anyone explain to me why my attempt to use my memcached cache backend directly from within a django projects "manage.py shell" is not returning my Book object b but is instead returning None? My exact steps were:

```
In [1]: from django.core.cache import cache

In [2]: key = 1234

In [3]: a = "test value"

In [4]: cache.set(key, a)

In [5]: print cache.get(key)
test value

In [6]: class Book():
   ...:     pages = 100
   ...:     

In [7]: b = Book()

In [8]: b.pages
Out[8]: 100

In [9]: key2 = 4321

In [10]: cache.set(key2, b)

In [11]: print cache.get(key2)
None
```

Thanks,

Comment: what do your cache settings look like ?

Comment: Does your model have a `__unicode__()` method? Try it without the print statement?

Comment: @karthikr I am using local cache via:

`LOCAL_CACHE_BACKEND = (
            'django.core.cache.backends.memcached.MemcachedCache'
        )

CACHES['default'] = {
        'BACKEND': LOCAL_CACHE_BACKEND,
        'LOCATION': '127.0.0.1:11211',
    }`

Comment: @RobL what model are you referring to? I defined the Book() class right there in the manage.py shell. if instead of print, I have book = cache.get(key2), book = None.

Comment: Django _won't_ error if it can't connect to the cache backend. Are you sure memcahed is up and running on port 11211? You should be able to telnet to the memcache to see if it's working `telnet localhost 11211`.

Comment: @vishen Yes I can connect to the cache backend and could even store simple things (like my "a" variable above). This telnet command also works just fine.

Comment: Well, I'm stumped...it works on my machines, as one would expect.

Comment: :( Well just my luck...

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? Pretty weird.

Comment: Nope. just had to work around it by actually saving the classes to files which i could import.